# ESLint error for ElementRef<any> and EmbeddedViewRef<any>

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have moved my angular project to ESLint and fixed all linting errors except the ones for `ElementRef<any>` and `EmbeddedViewRef<any>`.

**Error:**
`Unexpected any. Specify a different type @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any`

Can anyone help me understand what I should enter in place of any at these locations?

```
const element = this.refElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.custom-filter-control');
element.appendChild((this.CUSTOMComponentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0]);
```

```
templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about the type of element it refers to. For example, if it's an input, you want to use HTMLInputElement. For all types you may want to check them [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.htmlelement.html).

And for the template, you need to provide a template context, which means what variables are accessible in the template. For more detailed explanation you may want to refer [here](https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/10/01/angular-template-ref-dynamic-scoping-custom-templates/).

Comment: It would be really helpful for me, and I am sure for others if you could expand on your points a bit. Maybe with a little bit of code examples.